# jquery explode how to do that

Tags: javascript, jquery, exploded

i have a question for you...

for the first lets say i have a variable on javascript like this..

```
var string = 'a,b,c';
var exploded = string.split(',');
```

and then i have a html element like this

```
<ul id='myTags'>
</ul>
```

and my question is.. how to create / append to inside of my " **ul id='myTags'** " so it will be like this...

```
<ul id='myTags'>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#myTags').append('<li>'+ exploded.join('</li><li>') +'</li>');
```

Comment: You're on fire today: I think that's the third in a row that I just gave you a +1 for the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var stringLI = "";
for (i=0;i<exploded.length;i++) {
   stringLI += "<li>"+exploded[i]+"</li>";
}
$("#myTags").append(stringLI);
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to only append once:

**Jquery**

```
var string = 'a,b,c';
var exploded = string.split(',');
var items = [];

$.each(exploded, function() {
    items.push('<li>'+this+'</li>');
}); 

$('#myTags').append( items.join('') );
```